# Which is better for "undo" in computing: 撤消 or 撤销

Tags: translation

I first learned that 撤销 was the word for undo in computing terminology, for example to undo a database change or to undo a Git commit. However I've also encountered 撤消 for this same purpose.

According to cedict, 撤消 is a "variant of 撤销". Does that imply that 撤销 is the proper way and 撤消 is perhaps a common misspelling?

Are they both acceptable? Is one of them preferred?

Comment: 撤销 is the preferred one. 撤消 is a modern misspelling but accepted for many people use it.

Comment: 消 is the common form meaning "dissapear" "eliminate". But 销 is used in many certain collocations such as 销声匿迹 销假 销毁 销刃 销沉 etc.

Comment: @TooskyHierot Would you like to write that up as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the standard form is 撤销 according to [现代汉语规范词典第3版](http://www.jiaodui.com/bbs/simple/?t9865.html)

销 has the meaning to destroy, 撤销 is to destroy the current changes
消 has a passive meaning. Since 撤消 is an active action, 撤销 is more proper